# Update contents of TextView in Android TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, tablelayout

I have a table of 7 columns and 15 rows, each cell contains one TextView. I want to know if there is a way of updating the contents of individual TextView without referring to its id - i.e. by being able to locate its position in the table.

I can get the existing values of each cell by using code below, but can't see way of adapting this to change cell values.

```
 private View getCellAtPos(TableLayout table, int pos) {
    TableRow row = (TableRow) table.getChildAt(pos /7);
    return row.getChildAt(pos % 7);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function getCellAtPos returns a View Object. You simply have to typecast it to TextView object as View does not have a setText() method.

```
    TextView tv=(TextView)getCellAtPos(table,pos);
    tv.setText("abc");
```